# Calling C APIs from C++ missing output of printf statements

Tags: c++, c, linux

Lets go by example code.

ctest1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void ctest1(int *i)
{
   printf("This is from ctest1\n"); // output of this is missing
   *i=15;
   return;
}
```

ctest2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void ctest2(int *i)
{
   printf("This is from ctest2\n"); // output of this is missing
   *i=100;
   return;
}
```

ctest.h

```
void ctest1(int *);
void ctest2(int *);
```

Now lets make c library from that

```
gcc -Wall -c ctest1.c ctest2.c
ar -cvq libctest.a ctest1.o ctest2.o
```

Now lets make cpp based file which will use this c apis
prog.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
#include"ctest.h"
}
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x;
  ctest1(&x);
  std::cout << "Value is" << x;
  ctest2(&x);
  std::cout << "Value is" << x;

}
```

Now lets compile this c++ program with C library

```
g++ prog.cpp libctest.a
```

Now run it like

```
./a.out
```

Output is :
**Value is5Value is100**

But here values are correct. It means they have called c apis correctly. But output of those printf statements are missing.

What i am missing?

Comment: why using `return` in function defination ?

Comment: It works fine on my machine. Do you launch it with './a.out'?. Try to put `fflush(stdout);` after printf.

Comment: it is working fine for me.
output is :
This is from ctest1
Value is15This is from ctest2
Value is100

Comment: @Marian yes i am launching it with ./a.out in my Ubuntu linux 64 bit machine.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add printf's and forgot to regenerate the library?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès you catch it....i was generating each time new library but somehow library was not getting updated. dont know. I have deleted older one and now its works fine with new one. Please update this comments with your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works well for me (OSX 10.8, LLVM 6.0).

You may have modified your code by adding printfs and forget to regenerate your library accordingly. You should use `r` (replace option) in place of `q`.

But be careful when mixing both input/output layers, it is better to ask for synchronization of both. Call ios_base::sync_with_stdio(1) to get them work well together, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/